# Failed to create a 'System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler' from the text 'Button_Click'

Tags: c#

In my windows phone 8 application, while trying to create a dependency property I am always getting this exception. what I am doing wrong, plz guide me.

> {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Failed to create a
>   'System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler' from the text 'Button_Click'.
>   [Line: 108 Position: 66]    at
>   System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri
>   resourceLocator)    at com.sap.View.HomePage.InitializeComponent()
>   at com.sap.View.HomePage..ctor()}

this is code-behind of Header

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuClickProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MenuClick", typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(Header), new PropertyMetadata(OnMenuClickHandlerChanged));

public RoutedEventHandler MenuClick
        {
            get { return (RoutedEventHandler)GetValue(MenuClickProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MenuClickProperty, new RoutedEventHandler(value)); }
        }

        private static void OnMenuClickHandlerChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Header header = d as Header;
            header.OnMenuClickHandlerPropertyChanged(e);
        }
        private void OnMenuClickHandlerPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MenuButton.Click += MenuClick;
        }
```

this is in my user control (Header)

```
<Button Click="{Binding Path=MenuClick, Source={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" />
```

this is how i am including control on my Page:

```
<myControls:Header Title="{Binding Title}" MenuClick="Button_Click" />
```

this is in code-behind:

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenSettings();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

though not an answer, but I found an alternate solution.

added event to code-behind of UserControl(Header)

```
public delegate void MenuClickEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);
        public event MenuClickEventHandler MenuClicked;
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MenuClicked != null)
            {
                MenuClicked(this, e);
            }
        }
```

bind it in usercontrol:

```
Click="Button_Click"
```

then in Page:

```
<myControls:Header Title="{Binding Title}" MenuClicked="Menu_Button_Click" />
```

and in code-behind:

```
public void Menu_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```